# how to position several div elements with same margin in left and right sides?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to have 3 `div` inside a parent `div` like this [picture](http://8pic.ir/images/8a03jo7o0z9fxyxybk5z.png):
[image]

And when page size changes, only reduce the space between them without moving to another line and without using responsive design.

Answer (score 2):

You can use % percent insted of px - pixels.

CSS:

```
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
```

Comment: i do it, yet when change window size the last div move next line.

Comment: That is because you have a fixed width of the container div or on the last div.

Comment: I think all the DIVs have a fixed width here.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #999;
}
#wrapper > div {
  background: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```